# Syntax to dynamically add mixin to an actor

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor that sends messages to another actor. It also creates this other actor and does not know its type at compile time. On creation it needs to add a mixin. I am wondering how to solve this syntactically. So for example if we have:

```
trait MyMixin extends Actor {

  abstract override def receive = {

        case msg => 
            // Do something
            super.receive(msg)
    }
}

class Sender(targetClass: Class) extends Actor {

  // Here I want to create the actor such that I can add the mixin
  // eg. If I knew the class at compile time I could do the following: 
  // val target = context.actorOf(Props(new TargetActor with MyMixin))
  val target = context.actorOf(Props(???))

  target ! someMsg
  ...
}
```

So the question is how to combine the two classes for a run time creation?

Thanks
Des

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I would actually change the design. Instead of passing the `Class` as an argument why not pass a function that does create the `Props` or the `Actor` instance? And instead of adding your behavior with a trait why not use composition and make `MyMixin` a class that wraps another actor and calls its `receive` method when necessary?

Comment: The Props approach does sound better. However the essential problem is that this happens within a library that can work on any given Actor with no prior knowledge of the given actor class. So as far as I can see the problem remains the same. And yes the class approach does sound better but it needs to be the same Actor object, the reasons for which are beyond the scope of the question I believe.

Comment: I would guess that it is not possible: you're basically trying to mixin a trait at runtime without providing the compiler with information about the class you're mixing with. It won't be able to perform all the usual checks.